# Changing isNullable property for field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

Once in a while I encounter a field in my featureclasses that have their isNullable property set to No.

Is there a simple way using python to correct this?

I came up with this code, but unfortunately it's not doing anything.

```
print "Modify the RESERVE_ID field to allow NULLS"
desc = arcpy.Describe("OGMA_Final")
fields = desc.fields
for field in fields:
   print str(field.name)
   if field.name == "RESERVE_ID":
      print "Setting property for field"
      field.isNullable = True
print "Finished"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to set the `isNullable` property on the wrong type of object, a `Describe` object. You need to get the `field` object of the featureclass, then you can get/set `isNullable`:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> fields = arcpy.ListFields("WGS84Points")
>>> for field in fields:
...     print field.isNullable
...     
False
False
False
False
False
False
>>> for field in fields:
...     field.isNullable = True
...     
>>> for field in fields:
...     print field.isNullable
...     
True
True
True
True
True
True
>>>
```

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for responding.  I tried your suggestion, and also printed to screen the property as you did and that all looked good.  True all the way down in the py shell.  But when I opened up the data to view the field properties in ArcCatalog, the troublesome field still says  Allow NULL values   No.    How strange.   Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: @UserError - so you got this to work? I looked at it some earlier, but got nowhere.

Comment: I didn't get it to work. I was getting the same output as you were, but when I go to ArcCatalog the property has not changed. I didn't have much time to play with it so I added a new field, calculated the values over and dropped the problem one. Next time I encounter this I will explore your method some more.   Thanks again.