# DeleteField_management gives ERROR 000308 Invalid field type?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am attempting to delete a list of fields in a feature layer but am getting an error:

Execute error: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. [ERROR 000308 Invalid Field type](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00vp0000000r000308)

Here is a code snippet:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(roads, tmprds)

arcpy.DeleteField_management(tmprds, ["FIELD_NAME"])
```

I have listed the fields in my feature layer using:

```
fclass = tmprds
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass)]
print (fieldnames)
```

and I get a list of layers formatted like:

```
[u'FIELD1', u'FIELD2, u'FIELD3']
```

I have tried using both IN_MEMORY and real locations which don't seem to make a difference.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Couple of obvious questions that need answering, Your ListFields call returns field1, field2 and field3 but in your deleteField you supply a list of 1 field called "FIELD_NAME", this is clearly a field that does not exist in your dataset! Also what is _tmprds_ set to as this make be invalid?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - the names that I supplied were just generic field names so as to avoid printing unnecessary details. The list of layers returns e.g. u'FIELD1' and I attempt to delete that field using "FIELD1".

I have tried both:

tmprds = r'C:\mydb.gdb\temprds' and tmprds = "IN_MEMORY\\tmprds"

Comment: I don't think you can supply the field name as a list, I think you would have to create a loop to iterate through the list like for field in fieldnames fN = field.....
arcpy.DeleteField_management(tmprds, fN )

Comment: The esri help example uses a list and I have had a list work before in a previous script.

Comment: I see, I did notice two things esri's list didn't have the Unicode [u'FIELD1'] but rather just the string name ["FIELD1"] also they input the list variable not in brackets like this arcpy.DeleteField_management(tmprds, fieldnames)

Comment: yes its very strange because I am using the syntax from the esri help and I have assigned my field list to a variable. I use the exact same syntax in another script that runs fine.

Comment: are you sure that Field1 is not used as unique identifier field ? Can you delete it from ArcGIS desktop ?

Comment: Thank you! I was beginning to question my sanity... Turns out there were several fields that had "Allow NULL value" set to "No". I had removed all the obvious mandatory fields from the deletion list but it had not occurred to me that this rule would prevent deletion. When I removed these fields from the delete list the script ran as normal. I was hoping to set the Allow NULL values via arcpy, but not sure if that's possible - [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65845/how-do-i-change-the-isnullable-property-for-a-field) Thanks so much @radouxju

Comment: [str(f.name) for f in arcpy.ListFields(fclass)] will create strings instead of unicode text for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about troubleshooting this one:

1. Build the same logic using ModelBuilder
2. Run the script to confirm it work error free
3. Export to Python
4. Look at the script for the exact syntax

Also please note that you don't need to create a feature layer to delete a field - you can perform this task directly on the feature class.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  +1 for sound advice but I think most of us prefer to use **Copy As Python Snippet** in the **Geoprocessing | Results** window rather than ModelBuilder to do the manual stepthrough nowadays.  The code generated that way is much easier to read/debug than what comes out of ModelBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome @PolyGeo7.  You have a valid point.  I guess you can call me old school :)

Comment: Thanks. I created a feature layer so as to not make my edits on the original FC. I find the code from model builder to be unnecessarily messy, I prefer to code directly in an IDE although I can see the value in finding possible syntax errors. @PolyGeo I hadn't considered that as an option but will try it out for sure. Many thanks!